# How to link method to main method's if loop

Tags: java, for-loop, methods

I need to output the Sales on one column and the Income in another based on the if loop. I can not find a way to put my tier 1 with the first if condition, tier 2 with the second condition and tier 3 with the third if those tiers are in another method other than the main.

```
public class HW_1 
{   


public static double computeIncome(double salesAmount) {
        
        int base = 5000;
        double tier1 = (salesAmount * .08 + base);
        double tier2 = (salesAmount - 5000) * 0.10 + 400 + base;
        double tier3 = (salesAmount - 10000)* .12 + 900 + base;
        
        return salesAmount;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    System.out.println("Sales \t \t Income");
    
    for(double salesAmount = 1000; salesAmount <= 20000; salesAmount += 1000)
    {
        if(salesAmount <= 5000)
            System.out.println(computeIncome(salesAmount));
        else if((salesAmount > 5001) && (salesAmount <= 10000))
            System.out.println(computeIncome(salesAmount));
        else
            System.out.println(computeIncome(salesAmount));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1 you are trying to determine the "tier" in `main` when you should be doing so in `computeIncome`. I base this on the fact all branches of the `if` logic do the same thing in`main`. Problem 2 you aren't printing `salesAmount` at all, just the result of `computeIncome`. Fixing both issues is relatively simple, and could be done like

```
public static double computeIncome(double salesAmount) {
    int base = 5000;
    if (salesAmount <= 5000) {
        return (salesAmount * .08 + base);
    } else if ((salesAmount > 5001) && (salesAmount <= 10000)) {
        return (salesAmount - 5000) * 0.10 + 400 + base;
    }
    return (salesAmount - 10000) * .12 + 900 + base;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Sales    \t \t Income");
    for (double salesAmount = 1000; salesAmount <= 20000; salesAmount += 1000) {
        System.out.printf("%9s \t \t %.2f%n",
                    String.format("%.2f", salesAmount), 
                    computeIncome(salesAmount));
    }
}
```